# Auto-install Excel vba addins

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create auto installer that allows the user to open it and install the add-in automatically but i run in some problems during this.

One problem has to do with the extension of the file for some reason it allows the `.xla` but not the `.xlam`  if I leave it as `.xla` it gives me that the file is corrupt every time I open a workbook second problem when I try the `.xlam` it doesn't allow me to install it error 1004 unable to get add property form the `Addins class`.

Any help will be appreciated.

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit
 '
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Call for installation as an addin if not installed
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim AddinTitle As String, AddinName As String
    Dim XlsName As String

    AddinTitle = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    XlsName = AddinTitle & ".xlsm"
    AddinName = AddinTitle & ".xla"

     'check the addin's not already installed in UserLibraryPath
    If Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName) = Empty Then
         'ask if user wants to install now
        If MsgBox("Install " & AddinTitle & _
        " as an add-in?", vbYesNo, _
        "Install?") = vbYes _
        Then
            Run "InstallAddIn"
        End If
    Else
        If ThisWorkbook.Name = XlsName Then
            Run "ReInstall"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

 '
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Actuate the addin, add custom controls
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    Run "AddButtons"
End Sub
 '
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Deactivate the addin, remove custom controls
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub Workbook_AddinUninstall()
    Run "RemoveButtons"
End Sub
```

**Module**

```
Option Explicit
 '
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Convert .xls file to .xla, move it to
 ' addins folder, and install as addin
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub InstallAddIn()

    Dim AddinTitle As String, AddinName As String
    Dim XlsVersion As String, MessageBody As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        AddinTitle = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)
        AddinName = AddinTitle & ".xlam"
        XlsVersion = .FullName '< could be anywhere

         'check the addin's not installed in
         'UserLibraryPath (error handling)
        If Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName) = Empty Then

            .IsAddin = True '< hide workbook window

             'move & save as .xla file
            .SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName

             'go thru the add-ins collection to see if it's listed
            If Listed Then
                 'check this addins checkbox in the addin dialog box
                AddIns(AddinTitle).Installed = True '<--Error happening if .xlam format
            Else
                 'it's not listed (not previously installed)
                 'add it to the addins collection
                 'and check this addins checkbox
                AddIns.Add(ThisWorkbook.FullName, True) _
                .Installed = True
            End If

            Kill XlsVersion '< delete .xls version

             'inform user...
            MessageBody = AddinTitle & " has been installed - " & _
            "to access the tools available in" & _
            vbNewLine & _
            "this addin, you will find a button in the 'Tools' " & _
            "menu for your use"
            If BooksAreOpen Then '< quit if no other books are open
                .Save
                MsgBox MessageBody & "...", , AddinTitle & _
                " Installation Status..."
            Else
                If MsgBox(MessageBody & " the" & vbNewLine & _
                "next time you open Excel." & _
                "" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Quit Excel?...", vbYesNo, _
                AddinTitle & " Installation Status...") = vbYes Then
                    Application.Quit
                Else
                    .Save
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End With
End Sub


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Checks if this addin is in the addin collection
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Function Listed() As Boolean

    Dim Addin As Addin, AddinTitle As String

    Listed = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        AddinTitle = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)
        For Each Addin In AddIns
            If Addin.Title = AddinTitle Then
                Listed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Check if any workbooks are open
 ' (this workbook & startups excepted)
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Function BooksAreOpen() As Boolean
     '
    Dim Wb As Workbook, OpenBooks As String

     'get a list of open books
    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        With Wb
            If Not (.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name _
            Or .Path = Application.StartupPath) Then
                OpenBooks = OpenBooks & .Name
            End If
        End With
    Next
    If OpenBooks = Empty Then
        BooksAreOpen = False
    Else
        BooksAreOpen = True
    End If
End Function


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Replace addin with another version if installed
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub ReInstall()

    Dim AddinName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        AddinName = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4) & ".xla"

         'check if 'addin' is already installed
         'in UserLibraryPath (error handling)
        If Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName) = Empty Then

             'install if no previous version exists
            Call InstallAddIn

        Else
             'delete installed version & replace with this one if ok
            If MsgBox(" The target folder already contains " & _
            "a file with the same name... " & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            " (That file was last modified on: " & _
            Workbooks(AddinName) _
            .BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time") & ")" & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            " Would you like to replace the existing file with " & _
            "this one? " & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            " (This file was last modified on: " & _
            .BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time") & ")", _
            vbYesNo, "Add-in Is In Place - " & _
            "Confirm File Replacemant...") = vbYes Then
                Workbooks(AddinName).Close False
                Kill Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName
                Call InstallAddIn
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Convert .xla file to .xls format
 ' and move it to default file path
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub RemoveAddIn()

    Dim AddinTitle As String, AddinName As String
    Dim XlaVersion As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook
        AddinTitle = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)
        AddinName = AddinTitle & ".xla"
        XlaVersion = .FullName

         'check the 'addin' is not already removed
         'from UserLibraryPath (error handling)
        If Not Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName) = Empty _
        Then

            .Sheets(1).Cells.ClearContents '< cleanup
            Call RemoveButtons

             'move & save as .xls file
            .SaveAs Application.DefaultFilePath & _
            "\" & AddinTitle & ".xls"

            Kill XlaVersion '< delete .xla version

             'uncheck checkbox in the addin dialog box
            AddIns(AddinTitle).Installed = False
            .IsAddin = False '< show workbook window
            .Save

             'inform user and close
            MsgBox "The addin '" & AddinTitle & "' has been " & _
            "removed and converted to an .xls file." & _
            vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Should you later wish to re-install this as " & _
            "an addin, open the .xls file which" & _
            vbNewLine & "can now be found in " & _
            Application.DefaultFilePath & _
            " as: '" & .Name & "'"
            .Close
        End If

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Add addin control buttons
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub AddButtons()

     'change 'Startups...' to suit
    Const MyControl As String = "Startups..."
     'change 'Manage Startups' to suit
    Const MyControlCaption As String = "Manage Startups"

    Dim AddinTitle As String, Mybar As Object

    AddinTitle = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)

    Call RemoveButtons

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set Mybar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar") _
    .Controls("Tools").Controls _
    .Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=13)
     '
    With Mybar
        .BeginGroup = True
        .Caption = MyControl
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        .Controls.Add.Caption = MyControlCaption
        .Controls(MyControlCaption).OnAction = "ShowStartupForm"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        With .Controls.Add
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Caption = "Case " & AddinTitle
        End With
        .Controls("Case change " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "ULCase.UpperMacro"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
        .Controls.Add.Caption = "Remove " & AddinTitle
        .Controls("Remove " & AddinTitle).OnAction = "Module1.RemoveAddIn"
         '-------------------------------------------------------------
    End With
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Set Mybar = Nothing
    Set Mybar = Application.CommandBars("Tools") _
    .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=13)
    Resume Next
End Sub
 '
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Purpose : Remove addin control buttons
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
Private Sub RemoveButtons()
     '
     'change 'Startups...' to suit
    Const MyControl As String = "Startups..."
    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .CommandBars("Tools").Controls(MyControl).Delete
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar") _
        .Controls("Tools").Controls(MyControl).Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just write a neat explanation of how to install any add-in...

Comment: That would be really easy but some people are not IT literate so will not be bothered to do that so in the end will not use it and i will need to go and do it myself...

Comment: It would be helpful if you included only the code that is relevant, by creating a **[mcve]**.  Also see [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @QuickSilver yeah - not IT literate - have to teach them every day... a good instruction doc does help...

Comment: @SolarMike i thought that as well be some can't be asked to learn new things so i decided to do a auto installer open and everything is done for them but run in some problems. I'll get to the bottom of it in the end...

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with `AddinTitle = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)` given that .xls & .xlsx have different numbers of characters.

Comment: @jeffreyweir I tried with with 4 and 5 difference between them is one is leaving a dot at the end of the name but still that's not why is not working for me.

Comment: Are you positive? What if you swap out the 4 for a variable, that you set earlier depending on whether .xls or .xlsx and retest. You're going to need to do that anyways I imagine to get the name saved as intended.

Comment: @jeffreyweir You are absolutely right will correct that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem in the end so it did had to do with the save method failed.

So instead of the below line:

```
.SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName
```

Changed with this and it worked obviously I changed some parts of the code based on your suggestions.

```
.SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName, 55
```

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda you just need to change that line of code above in the procedure and everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with `AddinTitle = Left(.Name, Len(.Name) - 4)` as the hardcoded 4 will have to be adjusted between .xls & .xlsx extentions, or otherwise you could be left with a double period i.e. ..

Comment: i tried both ways but still no luck with it the problem still occurs with the format of the file i think. Is .xlam not an correct addin extension?

Comment: To check, can you add `debug.print Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName` before the line that causes the error, just to double check you're getting what you want?

Comment: @jeffreweir I made the changes and debugs and it saves with the right format but say for example i do it manually and save it as addin load it and it works but when i do it through code it doesn't so i still think it's not save properly with the right format.

Answer (score 1):

While saving the file, the [FileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) option needs to be mentioned as well.

So instead of

```
.SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinName
```

you can mention the file format as

```
.SaveAs Application.UserLibraryPath & AddinTitle FileFormat:=xlAddin
```

### Another problem

You cannot `Kill` the file the current code is running from.

Basically, all the `Kill ...` statements in the code would produce permission error, because the running code would have put a lock on the file and the vba `Kill` is not a synchronous function.

Comment: This is an old post but I think that the file format is coded as 55 for addins if I’m not mistaken. Regarding the kill statement I do not understand if you can provide documentation on it that will make sense that will be great.

Comment: 55 is the code for `*.xlam`, and 18 is the code for `*.xla` extension, as described in the above link.

Comment: To quote the [VBA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/kill-statement):
_"An error also occurs if you try to use Kill to delete an open file."_